Issues Displaying PDF in iframe on Mobile Devices in C# MVC Application
I am experiencing an issue with displaying PDF files in an iframe on mobile devices in my C# MVC application. The PDF files are accessed from my server. Here is a snippet of the JavaScript code I'm using to embed the PDF:
if (fileType === 'pdf') {
    contentElement = document.createElement('iframe');
    contentElement.className = 'content-frame';
    contentElement.src = `${fileUrl}#toolbar=0&zoom=FitH`;
    contentElement.style.width = '100%';
    contentElement.style.height = '100vh';
    contentElement.type = 'application/pdf';
}

The problem occurs when I access the PDF files via https://localhost/file/3223.pdf on a mobile screen (simulated using the browser's inspect element feature). The iframe does not display the PDF on mobile screens, whereas it works perfectly on normal desktop screen sizes.
For instance, when I use an external PDF URL like https://www.princexml.com/samples/invoice/invoicesample.pdf, it displays correctly on both normal and mobile screen sizes.
Could someone help me understand why the PDF from my server does not display on mobile devices but works on desktop screens? Are there any specific settings or configurations I need to adjust to ensure proper rendering on mobile devices?

Yes it's totally normal you cannot display PDF on mobile that's why it's working on a simulated desktop device but not on a mobile one. More information for this issue there : html - Embed PDF in mobile browser

Thanks for your comment @Floran, but as I mentioned in my question. I can display this pdf https://www.princexml.com/samples/invoice/invoicesample.pdf on both (mobile, normal desktop screen). So why I can display this one but my pdf  not (https://localhost/file/3223.pdf)
